# NodeJS setInterval() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin, bitcore

Program doesn't call console.log(infos) in setInterval() method after some time. It continues working after several minutes but interval value differs from setted value, E.g. if I set interval to 200ms it will call console.log(infos) after 10 minutes and more. What I am doing wrong? Here is my code

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore');
var p2p = require('bitcore-p2p');
var Peer = p2p.Peer;
var Pool = p2p.Pool;
var Networks = bitcore.Networks;
var messages = new p2p.Messages();
peer = new Peer('127.0.0.1', 8333);
pool = new Pool(Networks.livenet);
pool.connect();

var  Infos = [],

process.nextTick(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    console.log(Infos);
    Infos = [];
} , 200);
});

pool.on('peerinv', function (peer, message) {
peer.sendMessage(messages.GetData(message.inventory));
peer.on('tx', function (tx) {
var transaction = tx.transaction;
console.log(transaction.id);
Infos.push({ "txId" : transaction.id });
})
});
```

Comment: And why would you have an interval inside `nextTick`, a handler that probably fires relatively often

Comment: nextTick nothing does not change.